# How to merge two almost identical arrays/objects (with underscorejs or similiar libary)?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, underscore.js

We got one old list and a new one. The Plan is to merge both even if some new key-value-pairs were added.

```
var oldList = [{
  id: 1,
  name: 'Michael',
  sex: 'male',
  goodlooking: 1
}, {
  id: 2,
  name: 'John',
  sex: 'male'
}, {
  id: 3,
  name: 'Laura',
  sex: 'female'
}];
```

AND...

```
var newList = [{
  id: 1,
  name: 'Cindy',
  sex: 'female'
}, {
  id: 2,
  name: 'Herry',
  sex: 'male'
}, {
  id: 3,
  name: 'Laura',
  sex: 'female',
  goodlooking: 1
}];
```

Now I am trying to merge these both together and get the most out of both by replacing the values of equal keys. In particular the merged list should look like this:

```
var mergedList = [{
  id: 1,
  name: 'Cindy',
  sex: 'female',
  goodlooking: 1
}, {
  id: 2,
  name: 'Herry',
  sex: 'male'
}, {
  id: 3,
  name: 'Laura',
  sex: 'female',
  goodlooking: 1
}];
```

Michael changed his name and sex, but stays goodlooking. John changed his name to Henry and Laura discovered her inner beauty.

Comment: are the inner objects always flat?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var mergedList = _.map(oldList, function (oldElem) {
    var newElem = _.find(newList, {id: oldElem.id});
    return _.merge(oldElem, newElem);
});
```

Comment: Shouldn't that second line use _.findWhere rather than _.find, since you're passing an object as the 2nd param rather than a function?

Comment: At least I couldn't find any `_.merge ` method. Did you eventually combine underscorejs and lodash?

Comment: From lodash doc: If an object is provided as 2nd param the created _.matches style callback returns true for elements that have the properties of the given object, else false.

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks!

Comment: Ah, I was assuming it was Underscore, nm!

Answer (score 2):

A solution in plain Javascript:

```js
var oldList = [{ id: 1, name: 'Michael', sex: 'male', goodlooking: 1 }, { id: 2, name: 'John', sex: 'male' }, { id: 3, name: 'Laura', sex: 'female' }],
    newList = [{ id: 1, name: 'Cindy', sex: 'female' }, { id: 2, name: 'Herry', sex: 'male' }, { id: 3, name: 'Laura', sex: 'female', goodlooking: 1 }],
    theList = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(oldList)); // make copy

newList.forEach(function (a) {
    theList.some(function (b) {
        if (a.id === b.id) {
            Object.keys(a).forEach(function (k) {
                b[k] = a[k];
            });
            return true;
        }
    });
});
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(theList, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: Super nice JS-only solution!

Comment: Great answer! Side question -- how do you handle support for ie8 when using newer JS natives like .forEach and .some?

Comment: @JoshKG, for `forEach` have a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#Polyfill. for `some` have a look here https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some#Polyfill.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this maybe?

will override everything from the oldList with values available in the newList and adds new values if they are present.

```
mergedList = [];
_.each(oldList, function(listItem, index){
    copy = listItem;
    newValues = _.findWhere(newList, {"id": listItem.id});
    _.each(newValues, function(val,key){
        copy[key] = val;
    });
    mergedList[index] = copy
});
```

Comment: Superb! Perfect answer, besides little typo: `newNewList` and `mergedList` should be the same variable. Here a running jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PGfgv/1654/

Answer (score 0):

Somethink like this:

```
var a = oldList.length,
    mergedList = [];
while(a--){
    var oldData = oldList[a];
        newKeys = Object.keys(newList[a]);
    for (var i=0;i<newKeys.length;i++){
        var key = newKeys[i];
        oldData[key] = newList[a][key]
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Directly use lodash's merge method.

```
var mergedList = _.merge(oldList, newList);
```

It recursively merges own enumerable properties.
https://lodash.com/docs#merge

Comment: i am not sure, if this is the effect I was searching for. Does it not just "add" this to arrays to a larger one?